# spark sortByKey case class

Tags: sorting, apache-spark, case-class

spark sortByKey  key is type of Case Class

```
rdd.filter(line => {
  if(StringUtils.isEmpty(line)){
    false
  }else{
    true
  }
}).map(line => {
    val array = line.split(",")
  (OrderedKey(array(0),array(1)),array(2))
}).repartition(1).sortByKey(true).foreach(println(_))
```

case class OrderedKey(k1:String,k2:String)

but the result not sort ! why ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide an ordering under which your case class instances can be compared. The `sortByKey()` transformation will then use this ordering to sort your `OrderedKey` keys.

The following is an example of an ordering in the order of the parameters to the case class:

```
case class OrderedKey(k1: String, k2: String) extends Ordered[OrderedKey] {
  import scala.math.Ordered.orderingToOrdered
  def compare(that: OrderedKey): Int = (this.k1, this.k2) compare (that.k1, that.k2)
}
```

Comment: there is implicit 
implicit val sortOrderKey = new Ordering[OrderedKey] {
       override def compare(x: OrderedKey, y: OrderedKey) = {
                 (x.k1, x.k2) compare (x.k1, y.k2)
            }
but not sort   ,   when  set  repartition(1)   right